# sed remove digits at end of the line

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I need to find out how to delete *up to* 10 digits that are at the end of the line in my text file using sed.

For example if I have this:

```
ajsdlfkjasldf1234567890
asdlkjfalskdjf123456
adsf;lkjasldfkjas123
```

it should become:

```
ajsdlfkjasldf
asdlkjfalskdjf
adsf;lkjasldfkjas
```

can anyone help?

I have this, but its not working:

```
sed 's/[0-9]{10}$//g'
```

Comment: I think that would only work if you have exactly ten numbers.

Comment: yep, can you improve it to make it work? I've been trying but I cant :s

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
     sed 's/[0-9]+$//'
```

Your command would only match and delete exactly 10 digits at the end of line and only, if you enabled extended regular expressions (-E or -r, depending on your version of sed).

You should try

```
     sed -r 's/[0-9]{1,10}$//'
```

Answer (score 2):

The following should work:

```
sed 's/[0-9]\{1,10\}$//' file
```

Regex syntax in `sed` requires backslashes before the brackets to use them for repetition, unless you use an extended regex option.

Answer (score 0):

A quick look [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html) suggests you should try this:

```
$ sed 's/[0-9]\{0,10\}$//g'
```

{ } should be escaped, unless you switch to extended regex syntax:

```
$ sed -r 's/[0-9]{0,10}$//g'
```