# Replace the last digit for another digit

Tags: sed

I would like to replace each digit 6 that is at the end of each text line below (file source.txt) by the digit 5 using bash.

File content source.txt:

```
17692186044416
36184372088832
70368744177664
140737488356328
281474976710666
562949963421312
1126899906842624
2251799813686248
4503699627370496
9007199264740992
18014398609481984
36028797018963968
72057694037927936
144115188075856872
```

I have been tempted the command below:

```
sed 's/\(.*\)5/\16/' source.txt > target.txt
```

But `target.txt` corresponds exactly to `source.txt` showing that there was no change, I believe the syntax for this `sed` command should be different when the pattern is numbers.

The expected content of `target.txt` should be as below:

```
17692186044415
36184372088832
70368744177664
140737488356328
281474976710665
562949963421312
1126899906842624
2251799813686248
4503699627370495
9007199264740992
18014398609481984
36028797018963968
72057694037927935
144115188075856872
```

I would like a help in understanding what is happening and how can I even use AWK or another other than sed

Comment: If you want to replace last `6`  digit in each string you need `sed 's/\(.*\)6/\15/'`. Related: [sed remove digits at end of the line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10707320/sed-remove-digits-at-end-of-the-line)

Comment: Just use `sed 's/6$/5/' file`

Comment: @anubhava so simple, and how many times I used this command for other tasks but in the case with strings. I believe that this is a simple question to answer and should I close the issue

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I can not make your code works

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `sed 's/\(.*\)6/\15/'` its worked!

Comment: @anubhava `sed 's/6$/5/' file ` its worked too!

Comment: These are two different commands, how come they both work?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew About the differences they work equally as far as I realized by viewing the exit, I believe that both are efficient, am I wrong?

Comment: No @7beggars_nnnnm `sed 's/6$/5/' file` is surely more efficient that using a capture group and back-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing last `6` (not necessarily at the end) with `5`:

```
sed 's/\(.*\)6/\15/' source.txt > target.txt
```

Replacing `6` located at the end with `5`:

```
sed 's/6$/5/' source.txt > target.txt
```

**EXPLANATION**

```sh
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \(                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \)                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  6                        '6'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        end of string
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -pe 's/6$/5/' source.txt > target.txt
```

Example:

```
echo '16' | perl -pe 's/6$/5/'
# Prints: 15
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-p` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default. Add `print $_` after each loop iteration.

`s/THIS/THAT/` : replace THIS with THAT.
`$` : end of the line (in regex).

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)
[`perldoc perlrequick`: Perl regular expressions quick start](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick)